# TestComplete, how to check if pop up window exists

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

So I want to create a check for if a pop up window withing a web page exists through JScript in testcomplete, but am running into problems with the window check. Here's what I have so far:

```
var MyPage = Sys.Browser("*").Page(MyURL);
var PopUp = MyPage.Panel(20);

while (PopUp.Exists == false)
{
    //do nothing
}
```

But the program crashes, saying "unable to find the object PopUp, because it hasn't appeared yet. Is there a way to determine weather or not a pop up window exists without crashing the program?

Comment: Is there wait until loaded function within testcomplete?

Comment: If there is I don't know about it, but that would definitely solve my problem.

Comment: is this related to js alert popup?

Comment: What's the exact error in the log? Do you use aliases (`Aliases.browser.MyPage.PopUp`) or fully-qualified object names (`Sys.Browser().Page(url)...`)?

Comment: I use Sys.Browser.Page name, is there any other information I can give that would be useful?

Comment: There are some ways to wait for object appearance and check its existence. However, they depend on how you address the object. Please post the actual code that addresses the popup object in your test.

Comment: I think that should have added what you needed, let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Use [**typeof()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```
if (typeof MyBrowser.MyPage.PopUp.Exists != 'undefined') {
    while (MyBrowser.MyPage.PopUp.Exists == false)
    {

    }
} else {
  //variable not defined
}
```

Comment: This fails on the first line for me, with the same, unable to locate object PopUp reason for crashing